# Comparacion Lista de listas y lista python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

estoy buscando hacer una comparacion de una lista con una lista de listas. Con este codigo puedo hacerlo entre 2 listas pero el problema sucede cuando es una lista con una lista de listas.

Busco editar mi codigo a corregir.

```
lista1=["paco","pepe","luis"]
lista2=["diego","mari","luis"]
comparacion = []

for item in lista1:
  if item in lista2:
    comparacion.append(item)
```

Codigo a corregir:

```
lista1=["paco","pepe","luis"]
lista2=[["artur","2"],["paco","5"],["pepe","2"],["luis","2"],["beto","2"]]
comparacion = []

for item in lista1:
  if item in lista2:
    comparacion.append(item)

print comparacion
#Busco algo asi como respuesta:
>>>comparacion=[["paco","5"],["pepe","2"],["luis","2"]]
```

Comment: @FJSevilla Me ayudas con este? Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si queremos algo sencillo, esto es lo que haría:

```
lista1=["paco","pepe","luis"]
lista2=[["artur","2"],["paco","5"],["pepe","2"],["luis","2"],["beto","2"]]
comparacion = []

for item in lista1:
  comparacion.extend([e for e in lista2 if item == e[0]])

print comparacion
```

- `[e for e in lista2 if item == e[0]]` devuelve una lista de al menos un elemento dónde el nombre de `lista1` se encuentre en el primer elemento de las sublistas de `Lista2`
- Con `extend` simplemente estamos agregando la lista anterior a `comparacion`

Comment: como hago para agregarle a `comparacion` una lista mas que va a ser mis headers cuando la grabe en un nuevo csv??

Comment: olvide etiquetar @Patricio Moracho

Comment: Martín, cuando respondes un pregunta no hace falta etiquetar al autor de la misma, te lo digo para ahorrarte tiempo, la notificación llega igual. En cuanto a lo que pides, puedes inicializar la lista en primer lugar con los titulos de las columnas. En vez de hacer `comparacion = []` puedes hacer `comparacion = ["col1", "col2, ...]`, sino reordenas la lista no habría problema y sino el `insert` como ya te comentó FjSevilla. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el item a buscar sea siempre el primer elemento de las listas anidadas simplemente itera e indexa este elemento. Es recomendable que lista1 sea un conjunto o que la conviertas en uno ya que la búsqueda es considerablemente más rápida con una tabla hash de por medio:

```
lista1=["paco","pepe","luis"]
lista2=[["artur","2"],["paco","5"],["pepe","2"],["luis","2"],["beto","2"]]
aux = set(lista1)
comparacion = [item for item in lista2 if item[0] in aux]
```

Si quieres realizar la búsqueda en toda la sublista y no solo en una posición (por ejemplo, que tanto `["luis", "5"]` como `["5", "luis"]` se validen) deberás iterar también sobre la sublista o usar la intersección de conjuntos:

```
comparacion = [item for item in lista2 if set(item) & aux]
```

Si trabajas con cantidades importantes de datos usa siempre que puedas compresión de listas, `append` es bastante lento en comparación.

Comment: como hago para agregarle a `comparacion` una lista mas que va a ser mis headers cuando la grabe en un nuevo csv??

Comment: olvide etiquetar @FJSevilla

Comment: @MartinBouhier si quieres agregarla al principio de la lista, simplemente usa `list.insert`, por ejemplo: `comparacion.insert(0, ["Nombre", "Valor"])` después de la lista sea creada en la compresión de listas. El primer argumento de `insert` es el índice donde quieres agregar el nuevo elemento.

Comment: Excelente, funciono! Gracias